# Generics class in Kotlin with two type parameters

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, legacy

```
class MapBuilder<T,U> {
    operator fun invoke(arg: T): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }
    operator fun invoke(arg: U): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }
}
```

of course it's don't work due to JVM limitations.

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/test/tests/MapBuilder;):
    operator fun invoke(arg: T): MapBuilder<T, U> defined in com.test.tests.MapBuilder
    operator fun invoke(arg: U): MapBuilder<T, U> defined in com.test.tests.MapBuilder
```

Any idea, how I can implement this?

Comment: Ofc that is not possible because if I declare `MapBuilder<String, String>` then there's no way to differentiate which method to call. It would be helpful you explain what are you trying to achieve to get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods could effectively have the same signature given unknown generic types.  Therefore the base case as presented is ambiguous to the JVM.  So you just need to give them an alternative name from which the JVM (and Java or other JVM language) would view them.  You use the `@JvmName` annotation on *one* or both of them to give them internal names.  This won't affect Kotlin and the name you use from your Kotlin code at all which will see them as they were prior.

```
class MapBuilder<T,U> {
    @JvmName("invokeWithT")
    operator fun invoke(arg: T): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }

    @JvmName("InvokeWithU") // technically don't need both of these
    operator fun invoke(arg: U): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }
}
```

Now you are fine and can use them independently.

```
val builder = MapBuilder<String, Integer>()
builder("hi") // success!
builder(123)  // success!
```

Be warned that if `T` and `U` are ambiguous you could get additional errors when trying to call them.

```
val builder = MapBuilder<String, String>()
builder("hi") // error!
```

> Error:(y, x) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:
>
> @JvmName public final operator fun invoke(arg: String): MapBuilder defined in MapBuilder
>
> @JvmName public final operator fun invoke(arg: String): MapBuilder defined in MapBuilder

You can also work around this problem if you can define your generics in a way that they possibly won't overlap and be the same class.  You *might* get the error depending on the actual generic parameters chosen, but at least your base declaration would be allowed.  This is described in more detail in [Zoe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343671/3679676).

Answer (score 2):

It's because of overloading conflicts.

Effectively, with your current parameters, `T` can be equal to `U`. If you're familiar with overloading, you should know this isn't allowed:

```
fun something(x: Int){ /* foo */ }
fun something(x: Int){ /* bar */ }
```

But for an instance this is:

```
fun something(x: Int){ /* foo */ }
fun something(x: Float){ /* bar */ }
```

Because they could be potentially the same, this would result in conflicts. How would it know which method to call?

With the full range, the compiler will complain. If you use `: SomeClass` on one argument, it will stop complaining. But here's a random example:

```
class MapBuilder<T, U : Logger> {
    operator fun invoke(arg: T): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }
    operator fun invoke(arg: U): MapBuilder<T, U> {
        return this
    }
}

fun t(){
    MapBuilder<Logger, Logger>().invoke(LoggerFactory.getLogger(""))
}
```

`invoke` will be ambiguous. The problem now only exists if you have two equal types; which does it use?

Now, your MCVE is extremely minimal. I don't know what you use T and U for. As a result, I can't give you any code examples. But here's what you need to know:

You can't have two of those methods with any types, because they might conflict. Even using variance will cause overloading problems if you use two equal types. So it would exclude `MapBuilder<Int, Int>` for an instance.

You could use a single method, or split them into two differently named methods. The name reveals it's a builder, so you could have `withKey(T t)` and `withValue(U u)`

---

There's no way to disallow T == U directly, without passing a `Class<T>` and `Class<U>` and checking those. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't understand that, even with `require` or other contract functions. Also, before you try that, using `: Any` doesn't work. That's the default bound. Remember, everything is an `Object` in Java, and `Any` in Kotlin.

---

You can work around this with @JvmName (mentioned in [Jayson Minard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53346277/6296561)'s answer), but you'd use two different method names if you interop with Java. It might be slightly easier if you only use Kotlin though. Java-Kotlin interop has a bunch of `@Jvm*` annotations, most/all of which are covered [in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname).

Even with @JvmName, it will still allow `<String, String>` until a conflicting method is called. If you want to assert T != U no matter what, you'll need to run class checks.

Comment: Any methods to limit types of T and U to make they different? forbid <String, String>,  <Int, Int > cases?!

Comment: @DmitrySokolov not when you have methods. Just edited the answer.

Comment: "You can't have two of those methods with any types, because they might conflict." Your example with `: Logger` shows clearly that's not the reason, because it's allowed but the methods can still conflict. There's no rule disallowing overloaded methods which might have ambiguous calls.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, but in the first case they both have the same bounds. Effectively something similar to `fun invoke(a: Any)` and `fun invoke(a: Logger)`. Obviously, with different types there's different actual output, but it still doesn't have a matching type in the same way, depending on the generic types. And I feel like pointing out that I said **effectively**. I do not mean that's what it compiles to, nor is it how it exactly works.

Comment: @JaysonMinard when something isn't technically possible, there is no way to directly solve it. Generics doesn't support `U !extends T`. The only way to assert T != U is with Class<T> and Class<U> checks, which is at runtime, at which point it's too late. The compiler will still complain about it

Comment: If you mean more ideas for replacements, that requires more code from OP. Depending on what those methods do, they could me merged, need separate names, or something else. It really depends on usage. Since all that's included is `return this`, creating code examples isn't feasible. There are still solutions included as text, which is more than enough. Code blocks aren't strictly required.

Comment: Just saw your answer using @JvmName; that is one solution. It doesn't make mine wrong

Comment: You are right, I mention that at the end of mine now, pointing at yours.